# How to integrate swagger-ui in my application

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to integrate swagger with camel project

following this example https://github.com/smparekh/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat

How do i access swagger-ui using this example project ?

I delopyed the war file in tomcat.

and access http://localhost:8080/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat/api-docs i get this ...

{"apiVersion":"1.2.3","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/user","description":"User rest service"}],"info":{"title":"User Services","description":"Camel Rest Example with Swagger that provides an User REST service"}}

BUT MY QUESTION IS - how do i access swagger-ui/index.html?

what is the exact URL to access swagger-UI?

Answer (score 9):

You must copy the contents of the dist folder of swagger-ui into your project's webapp folder.

In index.html,

```
  window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
  url: "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs",
  dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
```

you must replace url with this

```
 http://localhost:8080/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat/api-docs
```

For details, Follow this link to integrate swagger-ui.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Comment: I copied the contents of dist, but still can't access the ui...
What should be the URL?
Neither http://localhost:8080/social/ nor http://localhost:8080/social/index.html are working for me (my resource context is "social").

Comment: @hick209, the parent suggested to add files into `webapp/WEB-INF `, but that I guess would make them not accessible, isn't? Have you tried to add them directly to `webapp`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `http://localhost:${port}/${contextPath}/swagger/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

http://localhost:8080/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat/{basepath}/dist/index.html if you have copied dist folder as is.  If you have renamed dist folder, use the new name instead of dist.  replace basepath with basepath you have configured in web.xml.  The code snippet for that looks like this:

```
<init-param>
<param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
<param-value>/rest</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

To access swagger2 it is

```
http://localhost:${port}/${contextPath}/swagger-ui.html
```

Answer (score 0):

These are your Swagger Docs:

```
{"apiVersion":"1.2.3","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path"...
```

Now you need Swagger-UI to consume them. You can install it *anywhere*. There is no hard requirement that you put Swagger-UI in your project. You just need to edit the `index.html` file to point to your docs path (the JSON output above.)