# How to integrate Postman UI in my webApi app

Tags: web-applications, postman, web-deployment

We have integrated `Swagger` into our website as a separate application using `Swashbuckle`.[How to integrate swagger into a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496935/how-to-integrate-swagger-ui-in-my-application)

I wonder is it possible to integrate Postman UI into our system for one of our client. If there's any how?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to integrate the Postman UI with a project.

At max, you can use [Collections](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/intro_to_collection_runs) to group and save whatever API calls you need and then [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman) to run these groups of calls from the command line.

In other words, you'd have to manually set up and save every API call unlike Swagger.