# UI for generated OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, microservices, api-design, openapi, swagger-editor

I am new to OpenAPIs and want to find out the best way to deal with my situation. I'll describe the situation and what I want to achieve, hope someone can help me find out something good for my case.

**My Situation:**

I have a program in Microservices. Each Service registers itself and has some APIs. I have a Service Registry which returns a JSON response of all APIs from all the services which are registered to it, whenever I call a single URI. (In better words: whenever I am finished with deployment (using Wildfly), if I go to http://localhost:8080/registry/api/services , I see a JSON text representing all the APIs). This respond is in **OpenAPI Documentation**. I copy paste the text in Swagger Editor (editor.swagger.io), and I see my APIs there with their nice description and that is indeed what I need.

**What I am looking for:**

I would like to build another Microservice into my program. This Microservice should call the URI above and build the UI which I see in Swagger Editor and help me see my APIs and make test calls to them. I searched a lot, the only promising solution seems to be using **Swagger UI**, but I have no Idea how to implement it into my program. The Tutorials are all about integrating it with Spring Boot and I am not allowed to use Spring. I would appreciate it greatly if someone help me find out a nice way to implement a UI to see and test my APIs.

I tried to explain everything as best as I could. If any furture information is required, please let me know in the comments.

Best Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [How to integrate Swagger UI in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29496935/113116), [How to embed Swagger UI into a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46237255/113116)

Comment: thanks miss Kosova. It helped me to start, got into another mess with CORS later which I managed to solve and now It is working.