# Spring Camel -Swagger UI integrate - 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, html, spring, apache-camel, swagger-ui

I have been trying integrate swagger ui to a camel project and I'm able to see the api docs. I've followed up this thread to integrate swagger ui.
[How to integrate swagger-ui in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496935/how-to-integrate-swagger-ui-in-my-application)
(copied swagger dist folder of swagger ui into webapp and added route "rest("/swagger")" to access via routebuilder)

When I run the camel project and access the index.html file, I'm getting blank page. Under browser console, I see that browser is not able to access the css files inside the html file.
I tried removing "./" from the script tags in html file, but still getting same error.

index.html

````
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
      });
      // End Swagger UI call region

      window.ui = ui;
    };
  </script>```

RouteBuilder
    ```rest("/swagger")
          .produces("text/html")
          .get("/index.html")
          .responseMessage().code(200).message("Swagger UI").endResponseMessage()
          .to("direct://get/swagger/ui/path");

        from("direct://get/swagger/ui/path")
          .routeId("SwaggerUI")
          .setBody().simple("resource:classpath:/swagger/index.html");
````

[404 Error on Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIeBu.png)

PS: I'm able to see the swagger UI with all api docs details when I open the index.html file directly on a browser from the folder, error persist only when accessed after starting the project.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Loaded the js and css file into classpath and issue got resolved.